# What is "as English verbs go"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found the clause "as English verbs go" in one of the answers on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/56295/2):

> In *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p.113-4), this is called "motional *be*", and **it's very unusual as English verbs go**. In this meaning, be appears only in perfect constructions [...]

It was later edited to say:

> In *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p.113-4), this is called "motional *be*", and **it has a requirement that's very unusual**.  In this meaning, *be* appears only in perfect constructions [...]

I tried hard to understand the meaning of the "as English verbs go" clause but failed. Will anyone clear the meaning of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a set phrase.  Here's how [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/as-someone-something-goes) defines it:

> **as someone/something goes**
> when you consider what other people or things of the same type are like
>
> *'As history textbooks go, this one is pretty good.'*

I was saying the verb ***be*** is very unusual, considering what other English verbs are like.

This use of ***be*** appears only in perfect constructions.  Very few verbs have that property, so ***be*** is unusual "as English verbs go".

Actually, ***be*** has lots of different properties that are unusual,  but I wanted to focus on this *particular* use being unusual.  That's why I decided to edit my post.

Comment: So, should I consider it as a normal usage of 'as [something/s] goes/go' as Maulik V says?

Comment: @RuchirM Yes, I think I'm using the phrase the way it's normally used.  (I would have answered sooner, but I couldn't find a dictionary definition to quote―Damkerng helped me find one!  Thanks, Damkerng! :-)

Comment: Yes, of course, I said the same.

Comment: @MaulikV Of course.  That's why I said "yes" instead of "no" when I was asked.

Answer (score -1):

Since this portion is [**now** removed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/56295/revisions) from the original answer *(as I see the edit done there by the answerer)*, I'm taking this phrase as a normal phrase [However, in the original post, I found it quite *strange*].

> as English verbs go...

is a normal usage of `'as [something/s] goes/go'`

However, the best person who can explain this is the answerer.

Comment: Oh, what was strange about it?

Comment: something strange means one has never encountered such thing before! @snailboat